# How to ensure that only unique row combinations are present?

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables which can be called `set`, `item` and `assignment`. The `assignment` table assigns an `item` to a `set`, thereby my goal is to ensure that each combination of items is unique. Hence, if `item A` and `item B` form `set 1`, there is no second set allowed which is formed by `item A` and `item B`. A combination of `item A`, `item B` and `item C`, however, is distinct and hence ok.

My original approach was using a hash with a unique constraint for each `set` which is formed by the IDs of the associated `item`s. This hash would then be updated by a foreign table trigger on each insert/update operation on the `assignment` table. However, I failed in implementing such an update function and don't even know whether it's possible or not.

Does anybody know whether this is the way to go or whether there's an easier solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a deferred constraint trigger, or (what I'd do in this case) replace *assignment* table with an array column in `set` and a normal before update/insert per row trigger to sort the array, and and using a unique key on the array to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I like the idea of an array column, however that would lead to loosing the foreign key relationship, right? This would be problematic for me as there are legal and illegal set assignments which I test that way (together with some additional tables; I wanted to keep the question simple, that's why I didn't mention that ...)

Comment: @user1449306 you can always implement foreign key behaviour via triggers, it's very simple and perfectly reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers will not work on some scenarios. Let `set1(A,B)`, `set2(A,B,C)` Now one cann't move to `set2(A,B,D)` by dropping `set2-C` and adding `set2-D` assignments because DB must go through prohibited `set1(A,B)`, `set2(A,B)` state.
You should implement custom API, stored procedures or something with proper transactions which will check only final target state. Also those procs should place locks on updated `set` rows during the transaction. Because really what is updated is `set`.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, thanks! For your solution: you suggest still using a hash in `set`, but updating and checking its uniqueness with stored procedures without any triggers?